# XBee s6b internet

Tags: arduino-uno, xbee

For my project i need to send some data logged into a SD card to a remote server.
For this im using an XBee S6b wifi module connected to an arduino. ive had trouble connecting the xbee module to wifi. and also how can i set the ssid and other information through arduino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You configure the XBee with AT commands. However there is one important thing to know about the XBee: it loves to be in "data" mode and won't stay in command mode while you play with it.

You need to first get into command mode by sending `+++` with a delay each side of it:

```
delay(1000);
xBeeSerial.print(F("+++"));
delay(1000);
```

Then you can send commands:

```
// Set the SSID:
xBeeSerial.println(F("ATIDThis Is My SSID"));
// Set the wireless key:
xBeeSerial.println(F("ATPKTh!sI5mYk3Y"));
```

Once you have set the details you need to write the settings to flash and reset the XBee for the changes to take effect:

```
xBeeSerial.println(F("ATWR"));
xBeeSerial.println(F("ATFR"));
```

After each command you should really be looking for the "OK" response.

If at any time you don't sent anything for more than a few seconds the XBee will exit command mode and go back to data mode - at which point you will have to go back to command mode with the delays and `+++`.

It's easiest to configure the XBee using your computer and an XBee Explorer.

All the AT commands are detailed [here](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/Digidocs/90002180/).

Comment: thank you very much. so once i set the ssid and key and write them to the flash then how can i send the data that i want to a particular server over the internet. for example say that i have a server running and it waits for some POST data.

Comment: The X6B doesn't work like that. It is designed to create a virtual serial connection to another X6B. When not in command mode any data sent to it is sent to the destination IP and port. If it is in TCP mode and the connection isn't open it will open the connection and it will remain open until closed by the remote end. It is possible, if you are very careful, to get it to connect to a website to allow you to send a request, but it's not easy.

Comment: ok so can you suggest me something other than the xbee which i could use in my project. what i want is to send the data that i logged to a remote server over the internet

Comment: The most popular small module is the ESP-8266.

Comment: thank you very much i will look into it, if you know any place where i could quick start with a code please let me know.

Comment: There are examples all over the place, and hundreds of questions and answers on this site.